# Paypal Button Centering with CSS Grid

Tags: css, button, paypal, css-grid

## Question

I can center my button on desktop, but having problems on mobile. How should I modify my code?

### Background

I had a heck of a time centering paypal buttons on a [website](https://karialbro.com/coaches/) I built. It was fine on a computer screen, but on mobile screens it floated right and overflowed out of the viewport. I finally fixed it by changing `grid-template-column: 100%` to `grid-template-column: 5% 95%`.

### CSS

```css
 .paypal {
position: relative;
grid-column: 2/3;
grid-row: 2/3;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.subscription,
#content > div.coach-grid-4 > div.second-p2 > span > form > 
input[type="image"]:nth-child(3) {
grid-column: 2/3;
grid-row: 6/7;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="second-p2">


 <div class="paypal" id="paypal-button"></div> //Paypal Button

 <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
 <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

</div>
```

I am wondering if anyone can explain why this worked but the other way didn't. Or if there is a better solution. I'm trying to gain a better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add relevant HTML for you CSS?

Comment: I have added the HTML. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Can you please add generated HTML for frontend without backend PHP template code?

Comment: I just took out the PHP.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3qcszL5a/1/) what I supposed to see? I see only  "Subscribe" button, no "Paypal" buttons. Also I see multiple `p` elements without content and `input type="hidden"` which can't be displayed (it's OK, but they can be removed from example). See: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's simple: to fix your issue I need to reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Vadim. I have stripped it down to just the 2 buttons. I'm new to posting on this forum and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

When given grid-template-columns: 100% you had to change the grid-column to 1 and not 2/3 ..
grid-column: 2/3 and chose the second column but the first column has the same size 
Here is the problem that appears on the mobile that the first and second columns are similar to the same size larger than the screen size of the mobile

Comment: Thank you, Ramy. I appreciate the input. I'm still very new at this and want to keep learning the "why's" behind what I come across.

Comment: you are welcome. If you need anything you can communicate with me